# Vue plugin component with own CSS (style is extracted but not applied)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vue-sfc

I am making a Vue plugin that contains  SFC with its own styles. **I am using webpack4** to bundle. For production I use MiniCssExtractPlugin to extract CSS from SFC to separate file. Everything builds up correctly, **style.css is created in dist folder and my plugin is working but seems like css from file is not loaded**. Is there a step which I am missing?
Thank you

**main.js**

```
import SearchBar from "./components/Searchbar.vue";
const defaultOptions = {};
export let Search = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    let userOptions = { ...defaultOptions, ...options };
    let props = { ...SearchBar.props };
    Object.keys(userOptions).forEach(k => {
      props[k] = { default: userOptions[k] };
    });
    Vue.component("SearchBarComponent", { ...SearchBar, props });
  }
};
```

**Searchbar.vue**

```
<template>
 <div class="search">My search template</div>
</template>
<script>
 export default{
 }
</script>
<style>
  .search{
    background-color:blue;
   }
</style>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
let path = require("path");
const VueLoaderPlugin = require("vue-loader/lib/plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/main.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "search.min.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "style.css"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[name].[ext]?[hash]"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
            ? "vue-style-loader"
            : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

In my project, I just install my plugin from npm repository then I use

```
import {Search} from "my-search-plugin";
Vue.use(Search);
```

to import plugin, and then call

```
<SearchBarComponent>
```

wherever I need. The component appear successfully but styles and not applied.

Comment: I'm sure the OP already found a solution to their problem but If you're having the same issue and you're using vue cli then adding `css: { extract: false }` to vue.config.js fixed this problem for me.

Comment: @user2466601  have you found the solution i'm running into the same problem